# difference between start_logging and run.get_context

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-machine-learning-service

I just wanted to know the difference between  start_logging and run.get_context in azure ml.
when they are used? what is the purpose of each function??

Answer (score 1):

Great question! The answer depends on how you plan to create an Experiment run, either:

- interactively within a Jupyter notebook or iPython session, or

  ```
  Experiment.start_logging()
  ```
- as non-interactive script that runs from start to finish without your intervention

  ```
  run = Run.get_context()
  run.log("metric_name",metric_value)
  ```

I'd say folks accustomed to using pytorch and tensorflow tend to train their models in epochs which lends itself to interactive sessions.

Once you have an established data cleaning and training process it makes sense to operationalize into a script, so that it can be run on a remote compute cluster or within a pipeline.

the [Enable logging in ML training runs docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-track-experiments?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003930) has this info about om

> **Interactive logging session**
>
> Interactive logging sessions are typically used in notebook environments. The method Experiment.start_logging() starts an interactive logging session. Any metrics logged during the session are added to the run record in the experiment. The method run.complete() ends the sessions and marks the run as completed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit on @Anders-Swanson's good answer. `start_logging` will create a new run which logs to "the cloud". Even if you are in a current run (because the script is started from a pipeline for example), you get a new run. `Run.get_context()` on the other hand will *get* the run you are in, so if you are in a pipelinerun you will then get the `run` the pipeline created. If you are *not* in a run (you are locally on your own machine for example) then `Run.get_context()` will give you a run-object you can log to, but this will **not** be logged to the cloud, only printed in the termal.

We use a function like this to get a run object which always logs to the cloud, either the existing one or a new one. But I am still not certain if its a good idea :-P

```py
def get_or_create_run(experiment_name, workspace, get_root_run=True):
    """Gets the current run if we are in a current run context (i.e. in a compute
    pipeline), or creates a new run with the provided experiment name. If
    get_root_run is true then we traverse all the way to the root run if there is
    one."""
    try:
        run = Run.get_context(allow_offline=False)
        LOGGER.debug(
            "Found that we are in a existing run, using existing experiment and run"
        )
        LOGGER.debug(f"Existing run: {run.get_details()}")
        if get_root_run:
            LOGGER.debug("Finding root run")
            while run.parent is not None:
                run = run.parent
    except RunEnvironmentException:
        LOGGER.debug(
            "Found that we are not in an existing run, creating experiment and run"
        )
        run = Experiment(workspace=workspace, name=experiment_name).start_logging()
    return run
```